# what is the concept of "similar states" here?

Tags: vocabulary

Machiavelli was a product of Renaissance Florence, a city-state that was struggling for expansion and survival among a competing group of **similar states**. As a public servant and diplomat, Machiavelli came to understand power politics by observing the spectacle around him without any illusions.

A. I know what the bold means, but wondering what is its concept.

Thanks

[enter link description here](http://smartsheep.org/f-a-t-i-h-u-n-i-v-e-r-s-i-t-y-p-r-e-p-a-r-a-t-o-r-y-s-c-h-o-o-index-5)

Comment: ... Competing  group of similar ***city***-states

Comment: States similar to Florence.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you understand the portion in bold, what is your question?

Comment: I am also confused. Can you try elaborating and rewording the question, "What is its concept?"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, as the question is not crystal clear.  By that I mean that if there was at the time some states which were similar to that city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar refers to *city-state*, Florence was competing with other city-states, like Pisa.

The Tuscan saying *Pisa merda* reflects how Pisa managed to get hated by everybody in that period of the city-states, before the Granduchy of Tuscany conquered everything.